# how to sort array of object by date has specific format

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, sorting, parsing

I have array of object contain date format. code works only for ordering the day not for months and years

**My Code**

```js
const bills = [
  {
    name: "ghaith",
    type: "transport",
    date: "12 may 21",
  }, 
  {
    name: "Alex",
    type: "Restaurants",
    date: "15 oct 20",
  }
];

bills.sort((a, b) => b.date < a.date ? 1 : -1)
```

Comment: That isn't valid JavaScript. Please correct so that readers can see exactly what you're working with. Also, there's rarely a good reason to ever store dates in a suboptimal, language and geo-specific format such as "12 mai 21". Always use ISO8601.

Comment: This is invalid date format.

Comment: `bills.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime())` ... which of cause works for valid date shorthand formats only ... the OP e.g. did provide originally `"12 mai 21"` whereas it should be `"12 may 21"` ... it's fixed/edited already.

Comment: @GhaithDiab ... regarding the provided solutions, are there any questions left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the above comment ...

> *"`bills.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime())` ... which of cause works for valid date shorthand formats only ... the OP e.g. did provide originally `"12 mai 21"` whereas it should be `"12 may 21"` ... it's fixed/edited already."*

```js
const bills = [{
  name: "ghaith",
  type: "transport",
  date: "12 may 21",
}, {
  name: "Alex",
  type: "Restaurants",
  date: "15 oct 20",
}];

console.log(
  bills.sort((a, b) =>
    // new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime()
    // or directly without `getTime` ...
    new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date)
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this below code to sort your array of object by date has specific format:

```js
    const bills = [{
      name: "ghaith",
      type: "transport",
      date: "12 may 21",
    }, {
      name: "Alex",
      type: "Restaurants",
      date: "15 oct 20",
    }];


    console.log(
      bills.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date))
    );
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. And thanks for the working solution (hence the upvote). And also allow me a note ... There is no need to additionally assign the return value of `sort` to an extra variable. Since `sort` does mutate the array it is operating, `sortedBills` is equal to the (just sorted) `bills` ... `sortedBills === bills` is `true`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger thanks for your upvote and I have updated my answer as per your note. I think now its ok.